# Android Gradle - how to include shared object with specific folder structure?

Tags: android, gradle, shared-libraries

Normally when you use Android Gradle package, you can include individual shared objects (.so's) using configuration parameter jniLibs.srcDirs. .so file gets included in flat manner. But what if I want to include plugins into their own correspondent sub-folders ?

Also taking into account product flavors ?

I have uploaded at least one demo project over here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/syncproj/code/HEAD/tree/sampleScripts/AndroidGradlePackage

(In case if you want to play around by yourself - it's slightly simplified Android java-c++ project).

Currently folder structure is following:

```
bin\Debug\armeabi-v7a\libnative_lib.so
```

I want to add folder structure like this:

```
bin\Debug\armeabi-v7a\plugins
bin\Debug\armeabi-v7a\plugins\test1
bin\Debug\armeabi-v7a\plugins\test1\test1.so
```

There exists bug report over here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63707864

with status 'Won't fix' - but if this is not fixed - maybe there are some walkaround to it ?

I have tried at least what is mentioned on that page - 
plugins folder structure gets created, with *so.recipe files inside, but no .so files for some reason - someone seems to filter .so out of there.

Most interesting thing is that generated file build\native-libs\native-libs.jar
indeed contains 1. *.so and 2. *.so.recipe files, but only 2nd gets included.

One of solutions mentioned over here:

https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/the-perils-of-loading-native-libraries-on-android-befa49dce2db

Attempts to replace java's 'System.loadLibrary' - but aren't there any simpler solution to this ?

So this solution can include *.so.recipe into .apk package: (Just in case if you want to try to continue with my approach) (Must be applied to project link above after dependencies)

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        // See (*)
        compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    }



// See (*)
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip) {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: getCurrentConfigAbiDir() + "/plugins", include: '**/*.so*')
    // '/lib/armeabi-v7a' - same folder as in .apk package
    into '/lib/' + getCurrentAbiFolder() + "/plugins"
}

//
// (*) Walk around issue of not being able to add files recursively from sub-folders as well.
// https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63707864
//
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper functions
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Gets current Abi folder name, empty if not detected - for example "armeabi-v7a"
//
String getCurrentAbiFolder()
{
    String[] props = getCommandLineArgs()
    if( props.length != 2 )
        return ""

    String platform = props[0]
    String config = props[1]
    String r = ""

    android.productFlavors.all { flavour ->
        if( flavour.name.toLowerCase() == platform.toLowerCase() )
            r = flavour.ndk.abiFilters.first().toLowerCase()
    }

    // println r
    return r
}


String getCurrentConfigAbiDir()
{
    String dirToZip = "DoesNotExists"

    String[] props = getCommandLineArgs()
    if( props.length != 2 )
        return dirToZip

    String platform = props[0]
    String config = props[1]

    android.productFlavors.all { flavour ->
        if( flavour.name.toLowerCase() == platform.toLowerCase() )
            dirToZip = "bin/" + config + "/" + flavour.ndk.abiFilters.first().toLowerCase()
    }

    // println dirToZip
    return dirToZip
}
```